# text - find all lines without the specific expression

Tags: regex, text, regular-language, emeditor

how can i find all lines in text file, which do not(!) fit this pattern:

`xxx-xx-xxx.xxx`

(no matter the lenght of each part; 'x' can be any char)

i can find lines with this pattern by searching the regular expression `^(.*-.*-.*\.+.*)$` (using EmEditor),

but i couldnt find a way to find the negative case.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.emeditor.com/text-editor-features/coding/regular-expressions/) of emeditor states that `regular expression syntax is based on Perl regular expression syntax.`

You could use a negative lookahead `(?!` to make sure that your pattern does not occur in the line.

Instead of using `.*` you could make use of a negated character class `[^-\r\n]*` matching any char except the listed.

```
^(?!(?:[^-\r\n]*-){2}[^.\r\n]*\.).+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

  - `(?:[^-\r\n]*-){2}` Repeat 2 times matching any char except - or a newline, then math `-`
  - `[^.\r\n]*\.` Match any char except `.`, then match a `.`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.+` Match any char except a newline 1+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SybNxF/1)

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of EmEditor. If you use EmEditor, you can enter `(.*-.*-.*\.+.*)` into the **Filter** toolbar, turn on **Use Regular Expressions**, **Match Whole String**, and **Negative** buttons. [Using the Filter toolbar in EmEditor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN2WK.png)